# Изображения отображаются серым цветом

Tags: android, view

В приложении использую цветные картинки. Но при их вызове они отображаются в сером цвете. В чем может быть проблема? 
Тема используемая для приложения `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`
Сами изображения вызываю в `NavigationView`

Comment: Какие картинки, где находятся - в тулбаре или в навигейшн драйвере, откуда берутся и как туда попадают?

Comment: @anber картинки находятся в `drawable`, отображаю их в `navigationview`, вот так попадают `android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. 
Цвет иконок задается в самой `View`

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```